# Looking for a more compact syntax for Prolog

Tags: syntax, prolog

Prolog is a nice language. I use it occasionally, from time to time.

But approaching it every subsequent time makes me feel less and less comfortable syntactically.

The modern programming languages are moving to allow

1. programmer less repeating himself
2. omit unnecessary pieces if they can be deduced, or their names are just placeholders.

The DCG is a step in the right direction allowing one to write

```
 sentence --> noun_phrase, verb_phrase.
```

instead of

```
 sentence(A,Z) :- noun_phrase(A,B), verb_phrase(B,Z).
```

but its entanglement with difference lists makes it less useful.

**So what I am looking for are projects giving Prolog 
a more compact syntactic representation, while preserving its semantic expressiveness.**

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. I would strongly recommend you take this inquiry to a mailing list.

Comment: @Daniel Lyons What mailing list?

Comment: I'd try the [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/Mailinglist.html) one. It's probably the most active.

Comment: You'd probably like [Picat](http://picat-lang.org/) though.

Comment: Take a look at [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), this is a language based on Prolog intended for code golfing (so probably too compact for you). It has implicit variables, many built-in predicates, predicate overloading depending on types, and mandatory CLP(FD) use for arithmetic.

Comment: @Fatalize: WOW!!

Comment: You can find many examples of Brachylog programs on [the Code Golf SE site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=brachylog)

Answer (score 4):

Higher-order programming based on `call/N` is still a pretty much unexplored terrain. Major implementations like SICStus Prolog added `call/N` as late as 2006. So there is still a lot to explore. Consider `library(lambda)`, `library(reif)` (both [here](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/)) and other definitions using the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) declaration.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to look into in case of Swi-Prolog are actual language extensions introduced specifically by Swi-Prolog 7:

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=extensions

Another thing is Quasi-Quotation library which allows you to insert pieces of code in your own language (defined using DCG) inside "regular" Prolog code:

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=quasiquotations

The last thing I can recommend is the list of additional Swi-Prolog packages, some of which are specifically designed to extend the language, e.g. 'func', 'lambda', etc.:

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list